# Cannot install "lanyon" jekyll theme

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

Before I begin this, some preface warning;

My knowledge of jekyll is 0.
My knowledge of ruby is 0.

Though I do think I've done pretty well for having no experience and just stepping into it today. That said, this is all **completely** new to me.

I wanted to give it a try for my `github pages` for a blog, just to see if I could make it work. I am running into a huge issue with what I suppose would be called the *global variables*.

I downloaded `Lanyon` here; **[Lanyon](http://lanyon.getpoole.com/)**

I did the following steps, in order, from my **Windows 8.1 x64** machine.

1. Installed **python 3.4.1** ([link)](https://www.python.org/download/)
2. Installed **ruby** using the **RailsInstaller** ([link)](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/installation/#rubyinstaller)
3. Installed **rubygems** using `gem update --system` from a **PowerShell** console
4. created a new github repository
5. created a `gh-pages` branch in that repository
6. created a `Gemfile` in that branch, with the following text

> ```
> source 'https://rubygems.org'
> gem 'github-pages'
> ```

Then came the work with *Lanyon*.

- downloaded **Lanyon** and extracted it, I copied all of the files into a new directory
- pushed the entire directory to my repository on branch `gh-pages`
- tried to navigate to the `gh-pages` given url.

Now I did see the index page, it did have the *content*, but the theme wasn't working. The `css` files were missing. Per the instructions for theme structure found on jekyll's website, I made some changes; **[link](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/api/theme-api.html)**

- I moved the `head.html` and `sidebar.html` into a new subfolder under `_includes` called `themes/lanyon`, per the suggested layout on the api docs.
- I loved the `css` folder into a new folder called `assets/themes/lanyon`, again following those docs
- I moved the files `apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png`, `apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png`, and `favicon.ico` into a new folder called `assets/themes/lanyon/img`, following the example in the api docs.

Now comes the trickiest part ... trying to get the `{{ ASSET_PATH }}` to work.

- I looked at the file `_includes/themes/lanyon/head.html` and saw the 3 css assets had no variables.
- I changed them to look like the following

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ ASSET_PATH }}/css/poole.css">
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ ASSET_PATH }}/css/syntax.css">
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ ASSET_PATH }}/css/lanyon.css">
> ```

- I updated `_config.yml` to look like this, obviously filling in the [] variables instead.

> ```
> # For more see: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/
> permalink: /:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title
>
> exclude: [".rvmrc", ".rbenv-version", "README.md", "Rakefile", "changelog.md"]
> pygments: true
> markdown: redcarpet
>
> title:            lanyon
> tagline:          'lanyon theme'
> author :
>   name : Ciel
>   email : stacey.cielia.lynn@gmail.com
>   github : ciel
>
> paginate:         5
>
> production_url : http://[username].github.io
>
> Lanyon :
>   version:      2.0.0
>
>   BASE_PATH : "/[repositoryname]"
>   ASSET_PATH : "/assets/themes/lanyon"
> ```

But even with all of that, it still doesn't work. It *does_* work if I type the *absolute paths* to the files, but that's not how jekyll is supposed to work, from my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access ASSET_PATH, try :

```
{{ site.Lanyon.ASSET_PATH }}
```

Edit : You're using Jekyll Bootstrap (JB) variables, not Jekyll ones.

**site.Lanyon.ASSET_PATH** is specific to JB. Here it's '**/assets/themes/lanyon**'

**site.Lanyon.BASE_PATH** (**site.baseurl** in Jekyll) is the path from your site root to your Jekyll install.

eg : If you do *http://ciel.com/my/jekyll/site/* to reach you site : **site.Lanyon.BASE_PATH** or **site.baseurl** = '**/my/jekyll/site**'

So if you want to reach your assets from any page, you need to do :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.Lanyon.BASE_PATH }}{{ site.Lanyon.ASSET_PATH }}/css/poole.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ site.Lanyon.ASSET_PATH }}/css/poole.css">
```

Et voilà !

Comment: but seriously though, this is great. I'll give it a try in a moment, thank you.

Comment: Ok. I did what you said and I got __different__ results, but not the _right_ results. It appended __most__ of the path, but it left out the stuff from the __`BASE_PATH`__. What does that mean exactly?

Comment: You are absolutely incredible. Thank you so much. I don't like ruby so far, but I am really excited to get something working with it (assuming this really is ruby - it is, isn't it?)

Comment: I am having other issues related to links, which I've posted about in __[SO#24831066](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831066/first-time-jekyll-user-confused-about-page-links)__ and __[SO#24827657](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827657/first-time-jekyll-users-difficulty-understanding-bootstrap-theme)__ if you know the answer off the top of your head and want the free points.