# first time 'jekyll' users - difficulty understanding 'bootstrap' theme

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am a first time `jekyll` and `ruby` user - 0 experience in either of them. I am tackling them because quite frankly, I just want to.

I'm posting my actual question up top, since this is a lot to read. All details are included below though;

## ACTUAL QUESTION

1. What is happening here?
2. How can I reproduce this for my **Lanyon** theme so I don't need the fully qualified name?
3. How can I get the `BASE_PATH` and `ASSET_PATH` merged in my **Lanyon** theme as well?

## DETAILS

I've followed all of the instructions here; **[jekyll quick start guide](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-quick-start.html)**

and for the most part I'm not as lost as I thought I would be. But that's where it ends. I'm having a very big amount of disparity between a few things, not the least of which is how these *`global variables`* work. I am referring to **`BASE_PATH`** and **`ASSET_PATH`**.

If you look in the `_config.yml` file of `jekyll-bootstrap`, the general structure would look like this, with comments removed;

> ```
> JB:
>    version:  0.3.0
>    BASE_PATH: false
>    ASSET_PATH: false
> ```

Ok, so they say to replace those values with information relative to your site. This is where I'm getting tripped up.

1. If I download a **different** jekyll theme, this looks a bit different. I cite another post I made on stackoverflow regarding **Lanyon**, which has neither the base or asset path in it. Still I've checked in on other themes and some have it, some do not, but the consistency is not there.
2. If you continue to explore the `jekyll-bootstrap` theme, you can find a peculiar file in `_includes/JB/` called `setup`. The contents of this file are as follows;

> ```
> {% capture jbcache %}
>   <!--
>   - Dynamically set liquid variables for working with URLs/paths
>   -->
>   {% if site.JB.setup.provider == "custom" %}
>     {% include custom/setup %}
>   {% else %}
>     {% if site.safe and site.JB.BASE_PATH and site.JB.BASE_PATH != '' %}
>       {% assign BASE_PATH = site.JB.BASE_PATH %}
>       {% assign HOME_PATH = site.JB.BASE_PATH %}
>     {% else %}
>       {% assign BASE_PATH = nil %}
>       {% assign HOME_PATH = "/" %}
>     {% endif %}
>
>     {% if site.JB.ASSET_PATH %}
>       {% assign ASSET_PATH = site.JB.ASSET_PATH %}
>     {% else %}
>       {% capture ASSET_PATH %}{{ BASE_PATH }}/assets/themes/{{ page.theme.name }}{% endcapture %}
>     {% endif %}  
>   {% endif %}
> {% endcapture %}{% assign jbcache = nil %}
> ```

Now please remember, I have **zero experience in this language**, so I am going on pure, 100% speculation, but it **looks** to me like this is doing some kind of merging between **`BASE_PATH`** and **`ASSET_PATH`** to make `ASSET_PATH` one and the same plus extras. If I am correct, this would mean that if you had ..

> ```
> `BASE_PATH: "/myblog"`
> `ASSET_PATH: "/assets"`
> ```

And then you tried to call upon this ..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ ASSET_PATH }}/css/site.css" />
```

You would get the right path, which is `/assets/themes/bootstrap-3/bootstrap/css/site.css`,
or in the case of another theme, like my `lanyon` one, `/assets/themes/lanyon/css/site.css`.

This seems like the **expected** behavior, but it's that `setup` file that is confusing me, and twisting things around.

Pursuant **[another topic on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813329/cannot-install-lanyon-jekyll-theme)**; I was told that I should instead call the `ASSET_PATH` with a qualifier to its theme, like this;

`{{ site.Lanyon.ASSET_PATH }}`.

Or, in the case of the original `bootstrap` theme, I suppose it would be ...

`{{ site.JB.ASSET_PATH }}`

Now we go back to the `setup` file; in the `jekyll-bootstrap` theme, we can go to `_layouts/page.html` and we see quite clearly that `setup` file utilized like this..

`{% include JB/setup %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is happening here?**

JB/setup just calculate BASE_PATH, HOME_PATH and ASSET_PATH depending on your setup in site.JB global vars. Those are shortcuts that you will use in you templates.

**How can I reproduce this for my Lanyon theme so I don't need the fully qualified name?**

**How can I get the BASE_PATH and ASSET_PATH merged in my Lanyon theme as well?**

As Lanyon is made to run with the base Jekyll and not Jekyll Bootstrap, it needs some integration in order to work as a theme. The [Jekyll Bootstrap Theme API](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/api/theme-api.html) explains the process.

As it is a little touchy, I've put and [example integration in my Github](https://github.com/djacquel/jb-lanyon). First commits is JB base and last commit is Lanyon integration.

Comment: Yes, that answers it perfectly! Thank you so much. This was driving me crazy.