# first time jekyll user - confused about 'page links'

Tags: ruby, jekyll

So I **finally** got a blog going on `gh-pages` branch in a github repository using `jekyll`, and the theme `lanyon`. I **love** it. But something still bothers me.

On pages, the 'link' at the top of the article seems to default to a url I haven't really specified. This is what the top of my `[YYYY-MM-DD-NAME].md` files looks like...

```
---
layout: post
title: Page Name Here
---
```

Now, it renders okay, but `Page Name Here` shows up at the top, and is clickable, but I cannot figure out where to set the `base url` that it goes to. As it renders now, it does ...

`[site root]/[page full filename]`

but it should be ...

`[site root]/[repo name]/[page full filename]`

And I'm not clear on which variable in `_config.yml` I need to set to make this work right. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Jekyll Bootstrap a post url tag is like this :

```
<a href="{{ BASE_PATH }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```

Comment: I'm actually not using jekyll bootstrap, but the principle seems to be the same. It was `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}`. Thank you again for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could also work with creating a url variable in _config.yml

```
url: www.website.com
```

and then creating a layout for posts with.

```
<a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```